# GSON fromJSON having problems

Tags: arrays, json, string, gson

I have a POJO class as below.

```
import java.util.List;


public class LocationInfoDTO{
    private int _id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String fullName;
    private int location_id;
    private boolean isEurope;
    private String countryCode;
    private boolean coreCountry;
    private int iataAirportCode;

    private List<Geospatial> geo_location;

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public int getLocation_id() {
        return location_id;
    }

    public void setLocation_id(int location_id) {
        this.location_id = location_id;
    }

    public boolean isEurope() {
        return isEurope;
    }

    public void setEurope(boolean isEurope) {
        this.isEurope = isEurope;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public boolean isCoreCountry() {
        return coreCountry;
    }

    public void setCoreCountry(boolean coreCountry) {
        this.coreCountry = coreCountry;
    }

    public int getIataAirportCode() {
        return iataAirportCode;
    }

    public void getIataAirportCode(int iataAirportCode) {
        this.iataAirportCode = iataAirportCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LocationInfoDTO [_id=" + _id + ", name=" + name + ", type="
                + type + ", fullName=" + fullName + ", location_id="
                + location_id + ", isEurope=" + isEurope + ", countryCode="
                + countryCode + ", coreCountry=" + coreCountry
                + ", iataAirportCode=" + iataAirportCode + ", geo_location="
                + geo_location + "]";
    }

    public List<Geospatial> getGeo_location() {
        return geo_location;
    }

    public void setGeo_location(List<Geospatial> geo_location) {
        this.geo_location = geo_location;
    }
}
```

All there will be inside a JSON object, just one thing the geospatial attribute has latitude and longitude and that is a different POJO class.All happens good using `GSON` `fromJSON` except the `geo-location` thing is `null`;

```
{"_id":376217,"key":null,"name":"test","fullName":"test, test","geo_position":{"latitude":52.52437,"longitude":13.41053}}
```

This is a sample JSON.

Triggering in this way

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);

        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
            System.out.println("Array:"+gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), LocationInfoDTO.class));
```

EDIT--------------------------------

Changed the `geo-location` to `geo-position`

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says exaclty what's wrong. You have a json object there for `geo-location` and it expects a list. Even if it's a one element list. Change

```
{"_id":376217,"key":null,"name":"test","fullName":"test, test","geo_position":{"latitude":52.52437,"longitude":13.41053}}
```

to

```
{"_id":376217,"key":null,"name":"test","fullName":"test, test","geo_position":[{"latitude":52.52437,"longitude":13.41053}]}
```

**UPDATE**

Since there will always be one lat/long, you should update your POJO so that `geo_location` is a single `GeoSpatial` object, not a `List<GeoSpatial>`

Comment: Can't do it.I get it through a webservice.

Comment: And will it be a list if there are more than one? Or will there always be exactly one lat/long position?

Comment: Exactly one lat/long.

Comment: Changed it to `private Geospatial geospatial;` still the same thing.Its null.

Comment: but that's not the same thing. you got an `IllegalStateException`. We'd need to see more (preferably the stack trace and the structure of the `Geospatial` object

Comment: `Geospatial` object just contains `double lat/long` fields with `getters and setters`

Comment: you changed your object to be called `geo_location` but the JSON still says `geo_position` ... they do match in your environment, correct?